# как отключить прокрутку в textView

Tags: android

когда я вывожу много текста в textView я включаю прокрутку командой

```
textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

но если я текст прокрутил вниз, а потом вывожу 1 строку текста , то текст не видно. нужно невидимый бегунок прокрутить вверх. Как отключить setMovementMethod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
textView.setMovementMethod(null);
```

Comment: сам нашел решение